# Parsing HTML tags using XSLT/MarkLogic

Tags: xslt, marklogic

I am trying to convert an `XML` file to `HTML`. The `XML` file has a bunch of `HTML` tags of the form:

```
<item>&lt;text&gt;Line 1&lt;br/&gt;Line 2&lt;br/&gt;Line 3&lt;/text&gt;</item>
```

Ultimately, the output that appears in Internet Explorer is:

```
<text>Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/>Line 3</text>
```

When I would like:

> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3

Once I discovered `disable-output-escaping`, the text rendered properly in IE.  Unfortunately, MarkLogic does not support this attribute.

I was able to eliminate the tags altogether using `replace()`, but I cannot replace the line break tags with an actual new line character.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to either:

1) Render the HTML properly in MarkLogic, or

2) Properly parse the HTML tags in XSLT.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are asking for is to evaluate a string and convert it to an XML node-set. In it's most generalised form, this would be a very hard thing to do in plain-vanilla XSLT 1.0 . If you can constrain the problem to a list of non-nested elements without attributes, this might be an easier problem to solve.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin MarkLogic xdmp:unquote does precisely that - take a string and de-serialize into a sequence of XML (document) nodes.  See http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want this

```
let $foo := <item>&lt;text&gt;Line 1&lt;br/&gt;Line 2&lt;br/&gt;Line 3&lt;/text&gt;</item>
return xdmp:unquote($foo/text())
```